# RPG Game (Beginner)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, role-playing-game

I recently picked up a copy of Learn Python 3 The Hard Way, but found that editing and revamping other peoples code was a lot easier for me to learn. I've done a couple so far, but am having a really hard time understanding classes.

I decided to make an RPG Game to both help in my understanding, and to give me a goal to push me to keep learning. My end goal is to have a working RPG in Pygame. I want to be able to walk around a map and display global variables such as health, mana, etc.

For now I am focused on creating the main part of my game -- I've found tons and tons of example codes for battling, items, etc, but I wanted to build it from the ground up, and am having trouble with my character creation.

Short term goal -- run the script, and have each characters' stats pop up, along with a prompt on which you want to create (numbers 1-3). Each character has a list of 3 attacks which do different amounts of damage, spend energy + mana, or arrows.

Heres's my current, basic, main page of code, which I really wanted help with.

I plan on having enemy monsters drop arrows, and mana potions, with energy being restored on each fight:

```
class PlayerClass:
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, damage = 0, energy = 100, strength = 0, mana = 0, arrows = 0):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.damage = int(damage)
        self.energy = int(energy)
        self.strength = int(strength)
        self.mana = int(mana)
        self.arrows = int(arrows)
pc = PlayerClass()
pcStats = [pc.hp, pc.damage, pc.energy, pc.strength, pc.mana, pc.arrows]

class Swordsman(PlayerClass):
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, damage = 50, energy = 100, strength = 100):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.damage = int(damage)
        self.energy = int(energy)
        self.strength = int(strength)
s = Swordsman()
sStats = [s.hp, s.damage, s.energy, s.strength]

class Mage(PlayerClass):
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, damage = 30, energy = 100, mana = 500):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.damage = int(damage)
        self.energy = int(energy)
        self.mana = int(mana)
m = Mage()
mStats = [m.hp, m.damage, m.energy, m.mana]

class Archer(PlayerClass):
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, damage = 30, energy = 100, arrows = 500):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.damage = int(damage)
        self.energy = int(energy)
        self.arrows = int(arrows)
a = Archer()
aStats = [a.hp, a.damage, a.energy, a.arrows]
```

Here are the attacks I wanted to add, but didn't really know where to start:

```
{"1. Slash: "
            "2. Chop: "
            "3. Hack: "
            }

{"1. Fire Blast: "
            "2. Shadowball: "
            "3. Arcane Presence: "
            }

{"1. Long Shot: "
            "2. Rapid Fire: "
            "3. Arrow Barrage: "
            }
```

Comment: on Codereview there are rules about what is *on/off* topic. And "Here are the attacks I wanted to add" is asking about code not yet written, which is frowned upon. You might want to remove that from the question. But I'm sure you will get a few decent answers.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have much code written, so I'm not really sure how much help you're likely to get here.

A couple of points:

1. There's no reason to call it `PlayerClass`. Just call it `Player` since the word `class` appears right next to it.
2. You are using `PlayerClass` as the base class for your other three classes. But you are not calling `super` in your initializer function, and not taking advantage of inheritance. Try this:

   ```
   class Swordsman(Player):
       def __init__(self, *, damage=50, strength=100, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(damage=damage, strength=strength, **kwargs)
   ```

   And see Raymond Hettinger's [guide to using `super`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for more pro-tips. The idea here is to override the default attribute values on a per-class basis (dmg and str, in this case) but have the root class do all the attribute-setting, since it's all the same except for the values.

Answer (score 1):

## Review

1. Use inheritence, they derive from the same super class, but for now they have different constructors. Alot more typing ;)
2. You could use a `__str__` to get a visual representation of the stats, these can also be handled by the parent Class.
3. If you use `Python3.6` you could use the fancy `f"string"`, see the relevant [PEP article](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

@Austin Hastings has the right idea, using `**kwargs` to do all the attribute setttings.

I recommend to look up `inheritence`, and Python `__magic__ methods`.

## Code changes

```
import textwrap


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hp=100, damage=30, energy=100, strength=0, mana=0, arrows=0):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage
        self.energy = energy
        self.strength = strength
        self.mana = mana
        self.arrows = arrows        

    def __str__(self):
        return textwrap.dedent(f"""\
                                Name: {self.name}
                                HP: {self.hp}
                                Damage: {self.damage}
                                Energy {self.energy}
                                Strength {self.strength}
                                Mana {self.mana}
                                Arrows {self.arrows}\n""")

class Swordsman(Player):
    def __init__(self, name="Sowrdsman", damage=50, strength=100, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage, strength=strength, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

class Mage(Player):
    def __init__(self, name="Mage", mana=500, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, mana=mana, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

class Archer(Player):
    def __init__(self, name="Archer", arrows=500, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, arrows=arrows, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    archer = Archer()
    print(archer)

    swordsman = Swordsman()
    print(swordsman)

    mage = Mage()
    print(mage)
```

Comment: since a mage or swordman don't have arrows, I would set these to default `0` on `Player`, and not on the subclasses that don't need them. If later you want a Swordsman with arrows, you can pass this on via the `**kwargs`

Comment: Maybe link `f"string"` to [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)?